# Sublime Text 3. Anaconda documentation and autocompletion

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I am using the package Anaconda for Sublime Text 3.

I have found out that either the documentation is not alright or I am doing something wrong. For example, in this code:

```
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

If I check the documentation of `ssl` I don't see there is a function called `create_default_context()`.

I also don't know what attributes the object `context` I have created has.

When I type `context.` the possible atributes (`chekc_hostname`, `verify_mode`...) doesn't pop up.

Thank you on advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your Anaconda settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssl.create_default_context()` is present in both [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context) (from 2.7.9 onward) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context), so I don't know why you didn't find it in the docs. The `SSLContext` docs ([Py2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts), [Py3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts)) describe all of the available methods and attributes for an object of that type.

Without knowing your Anaconda settings, it is impossible to troubleshoot why the plugin isn't working as expected. The [documentation](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) is quite clear as to how to set up and use the plugin. If after carefully reading through it you are still having problems, please post your full Anaconda settings in your question (*not* in the comments).